# Do apple approve the app with different user experience for different users?

Tags: iphone, store

I want to develop one application which will be available on App store for purchase. Price of the application will same for all the customer but some feature will be unlock for particular organization. Is that allowed on app store to distribute application to all in same price but some features will be unlock for particular organization. App store will allow this type of application? Or do we need to distribute two different builds?

Thank you in advance.

Jyotsna Kadam.

Answer (score 2):

Are you accepting payment for the enhanced app features outside of the "in-app" purchases stream?  If so I do not think Apple will like that, but I do not know that they have any way to enforce it on their end.  I am not familiar with the ToS to know if this violates them specifically.,  Based on my knowledge it does not.

Ultimately Apple's review is to determine that the app you have uploaded for distribution is functional and does not violate the Human Interface Guidelines.  They will run the app and put it through its paces to ensure it is a quality build that the user will not want a refund for.  They do not care "what" the app does per se.  It is on you to provide value in what you have built.

Having the enhanced feature in your app, you will need to remember to give the Apple reviewers a way to test the "whole" app or it will certainly be rejected.  I can confirm that from experience.

Good Luck!

Comment: They definitely can enforce it on their end, by rejecting it.

Comment: They cannot enforce anything if there is no evidence of the external payment on the app, if the app never indicates a payment was made they would have nothing to enforce.  Not knowing the app I had to hedge.

Comment: Hiding functionality like that has gotten people's apps yanked. Popular app Camera+ disappeared from the App Store for months after sneaking a feature in past reviewers. Not worth the risk.

Comment: Hi Mystik, I just want to confirm that if price of the application is same for all users. But few users from the particular organization can have some key or user code which will unlock the future of the application, other user can't use that feature. Will app store allow this or reject? We will give user key or code to app store to test full application but not for all common user except particular organization.

Answer (score 1):

As long you implement it with all the other Apple Guidelines in mind you shouldn't have any issues. Many apps do this, they offer main features that do not require the user to authenticate. But if the user does then they are able to access a host of other features. But with that said you need to submit you app to apple, we can only guess what apple will say when they review your app.